# Definir css com php de acordo com o navegador

Tags: php, html, css

Hoje cedo fiz [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75295/problemas-de-html-em-diferentes-navegadores) pergunta.

O que preciso saber, é como posso fazer algo parecido com isso:

- Verificar se o navegador é ou não o Safari.
- Se for, `section#internal.services aside ul li a` deve receber este css:

`CSS` aplicado:

```
color:#666666;
display:block;
font:normal normal bold 15px/normal Questrial, Arial;
height:70px;
line-height:4em;
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso, com php?

Comment: A página html é gerada a partir de uma template engine como dwoo ou smarty?

Comment: @ricardo Não...

Comment: Como é gerada? poste aqui

Comment: @ricardo Perdão, sou novo em programação, não entendi ao que você se refere...

Comment: Postei pra ti a resposta, verifique. Testei aqui e está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Editei minha resposta, como não tinha seus Css dois links para dar o mesmo efeito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode buscar o userAgent, e verificar o navegador, e com base nisso, pode então definir seu css.

Segue o exemplo:

```
 if (preg_match('|MSIE ([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $css = "border: solid 5px blue;";
    $browser = 'IE';
  } elseif (preg_match( '|Opera/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $css = "border: solid 5px blue;";
    $browser = 'Opera';
  } elseif(preg_match('|Firefox/([0-9\.]+)|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $css = "border: solid 5px red;";
    $browser = 'Firefox';
  } elseif(preg_match('|Chrome/([0-9\.]+)|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $css = "border: solid 5px blue;";
    $browser = 'Chrome';
  } elseif(preg_match('|Safari/([0-9\.]+)|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $css = "border: solid 5px red;";
    $browser = 'Safari';
  } else {
    $css = "border: solid 5px red;";
    $browser= 'other';
  }
```

## Use da seguinte forma:

No `$css` eu inclui o CSS, e então você pode colocar:

```
<style> 
     section#internal.services aside ul li a { 
       <?php echo $css; ?>
     }
</style>
```

Com isto, importará o css corretamente.

Comment: André, como definiria o css assim fazendo?

Comment: A verificação funciona corretamente, mas não entendi como posso definir o css! Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode colocar o CSS dentro do $css ou então, você pode definir o css dele separado... <link rel="stylesheet" href=....> se caso for Firefox, ou se for os demais, você pode definir o outro css.

Comment: Mas como digo que meu elemento deve receber o estilo dentro de $css?

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo pra ti

Comment: Se quiser add no skype @Skyirn - srandrebaill - Sempre fico mais lá do que no site.. Precisando, só chamar. Respondo aqui sempre que vejo.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Deu certo minha resposta?

Comment: Estou testando, se funcionar irei marcar como aceita!

Comment: Ok, sem problemas! :)

Comment: @Skyirn Alterei minha resposta, verifique se atende sua necessidade.

Comment: André, fiz dessa forma, mas não funcionou ):

Comment: está dando em todos os navegadores que é safari

Comment: Consegui, obrigado!

Comment: Por via das dúvidas, alterei também o código com todos os navegadores, sugestão do @ricardo, para que faça a iteração correta. Caso tenha dúvidas, estamos todos por aqui!

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 3):

É possivel verificar o user agent desta forma:

```
  <?php
    $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

  if (preg_match('|MSIE ([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = 'IE';
  } elseif (preg_match( '|Opera/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = 'Opera';
  } elseif(preg_match('|Firefox/([0-9\.]+)|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = 'Firefox';
  } elseif(preg_match('|Chrome/([0-9\.]+)|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = 'Chrome';
  } elseif(preg_match('|Safari/([0-9\.]+)|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = 'Safari';
  } else {
    $browser_version = 0;
    $browser= 'other';
  }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        /*<?php 
            if($browser == 'Safari')
                echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">';
            else
                echo '<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>';
         ?>*/
    </head>
    <body>
         <?php 
              if($browser == 'Safari'){
                  echo '<span id="#internal"></span>';
              }else{
                  echo '<span></span>';
              }
         ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Como desejo do AP foi aplicado o `id` especifico ao elemento caso o browser seja o safari. É necessário que o estilho que será aplicado ao elemento quando no safari esteja no css.

**Adendo:** Ainda é possível com esta Super Global `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` identificar qual o `SO`

Comment: ricardo obrigado pela resposta, pode me mostrar como posso fazer usando o css no html? digo sem chamar um arquivo externo.

Comment: Por exemplo, se for safari `section#internal.services aside ul li`vai receber aquele css que passei na pergunta

Comment: Adicionei o meu html a pergunta, gostaria de adicionar o css utilizando a tag `<style>` para o elemento section#internal.services aside ul li a

Comment: Perdão ricardo, acho que não me expliquei bem. Eu preciso que o elemento `section#internal.services aside ul li a ` receba um css caso esteja no safari, caso em outro, receba outro css. Mas quero fazer isso no mesmo arquivo. Usando `<style> section#internal.services aside ul li a { ..........}</style>`.

Comment: Mas no meu exemplo você pode definir ele. Porém, não é possivel se ele estiver externo... Ele precisa estar no mesmo arquivo que está recebendo a página do CSS, porque não dá para interagir o CSS dentro de um arquivo .css, só se ele estiver dentro do <style>

Comment: @Skyirn Para o que deseja julgo que haja duas soluções uma seria a primeira que havia feito onde há uma seleção entre arquivos css (esta na minha resposta marcada com comentários) a outra opção seria a do AndreBaill