# Carregar arquivo php de acordo com a resolução da tela

Tags: php, layout-responsivo, mobile

Olá,

Sei que existem frameworks como o bootstrap (que eu uso) mas realmente quero fazer um template separado para dispositivos moveis.

Minha duvida é como chamar o arquivo php de acordo com a resolução da tela?

Comment: O PHP não tem como saber a resolução da tela, ele roda no servidor. Somente daria pra fazer isso se algo no cliente carregasse algo via AJAX dando esta informação. Agora, uma observação: não tenho como afirmar isso, mas provavelmente você está tentando resolver um problema com a ferramenta errada. Se quer aplicações diferentes de acordo com a resolução, redirecione a pessoa com JS. O que pode ser um problema, pois posso estar com a janela do navegador do desktop dimensionada em um pedaço da tela, e aí vou receber a aplicação mobile. Precisa ver se é essa mesmo a intenção.

Comment: Obrigada @Bacco agora a pouco achei a resposta que precisava, neste [post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75386/definir-css-com-php-de-acordo-com-o-navegador?answertab=votes#tab-top)  neste [post2](http://ptcomputador.com/P/php-mysql-programming/92500.html#.Vwh_HvkrIdU) tem explicação sobre o user agent, com isso achei a solução na classe [mobile_detect no github](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) e tem um video explicativo legal no [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cti76yTowoQ)

Comment: O user-agent é diferente do que vc perguntou. E isso aí desses posts eu conheço, e não funciona direito. Em alguns casos muito específicos, pode ser que o script acerta, mas se adotar uma solução dessas, vai sempre ter problema com dispositivos que não fornecem a string esperada. Pode ser que você teste em 2 ou 3 dispositivos bem comuns e tudo funcione, mas num caso real, só do usuário pegar um browser diferente (ou mesmo numa atualização do browser padrão do OS), já pode mudar tudo.

Comment: Entendo que o user agent é relacionado ao browser, mas acredito que apartir disso foi possivel estruturar a classe, é apenas uma suposição minha. Mas pq a classe não funciona, parece ter boas recomendações? Nesse arquivo de [teste](http://demo.techsofttutorials.com/detect_mobile_using_php/) aparentemente funciona

Comment: O "aparentemente" é a palavra chave. Com certeza vai funcionar em muitos casos, e é por isso que o pessoal adota estas soluções. A questão é, e nos casos em que não funcionar? Como você diagnostica isso? Tudo depende do seu público alvo. Se fizer um site pra uma Boy Band da moda, é legal contar com dispositivos modernos, e uma parcela que tenha problemas não te afeta. Se for fazer um site para um laboratório, em que pessoas de todo tipo e faixa de renda pegam exames médicos, aí você tem que priorizar o acesso desde um iPad até um tablet chinês. O "certo e errado" depende do contexto.

Comment: Verdade é um risco a classe não acompanhar novas atualizações e não carregar carregar corretamente

Comment: Mas estava pensando em ter umas 3 resoluções, "padrão" celular, "padrão" tablet e computador, já esta bom para começar e atender uma parcela considerável.

Comment: Um quebra-galho bom pode ser você ter no menu a opção da pessoa mudar a visualização, se quiser. Neste caso, o usuário não fica preso no modelo errado, caso haja algum problema na detecção.

Comment: Obrigada pelas sugestões @Bacco

Comment: É uma questão inocente que parece simples mas na verdade é muito ampla pois há diferentes formas de resolver. Depende de N fatores.